# Galleria thumbnails not displaying correctly

Tags: jquery-plugins, galleria

I have a galleria implementation with the Twelve premium theme.

I am having a real problem with the thumbnail rendering on galleries with mixed portrait and landscape images. The thumbnails for the portrait images are being cropped top and bottom, with only the centre showing. The image appears to display OK in lightbox and fullscreen mode but occasionally also appears cropped in the main stage area.

See [here](http://www.davidfirthphotographics.co.uk/gallery.php?cat_id=1) for example.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting thumbCrop to false in the theme settings?

```
Galleria.addTheme({
  ...
  defaults: {
    ...
    thumbCrop: false,
  }
  ...
}
```